# Scanning and switching Wifi networks on iOS 4.0 and above

Tags: ios, api, wifi, private

I am trying to find whether the private APIs listed at: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions still work with iOS 4.0 and above. I am trying to turn the wifi ON, scan the networks available and latch on to one of the networks. I am not going to put the application in appStore and it is just an experiment. I found many applications pulled down from the appStore but they seem to have been developed on iOS versions less than 3.0. I would also like to get an example if possible.

Please Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch the list of near by wifi networks and able to connect to them from our App in ios (Using private API for enterprise App)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784094/how-to-fetch-the-list-of-near-by-wifi-networks-and-able-to-connect-to-them-from)

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing as you, and after some research I must say that starting from iOS 5 it is possible to scan the network list using private API on a jailbroken device only. [This blog post](http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/) states the following:

> Last year Apple has blocked wifi scanners from App Store, however till iOS5 it was still available for private usage via WiFiManager bundle.
>
> In iOS5, WifiManager bundle no more exists however 80211 functions are still available via IPConfiguration bundle.

The API you linked provides an open-source tool [Stumbler](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler) which seems like something you were seeking. The tool is claimed to work under iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

Tried stumbler for iOS5 via linking to framework

```
/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/IPConfiguration
```

I could link to Apple80211Open, Apple80211BindToInterface, Apple80211Scan. However, I only receive empty WiFi scan results on jailbroken iPhone4S / iOS 5.1.1

The folks from WifiFofum did a good job and have a app on cydia which runs on JB iOS 5.1.1 and does an excellent job for scanning WiFi networks (BSSID, link level, SSID, channels, ...).

Comment: My mistake - started the app in the default applications folder (mobile user). Moved the app to the system's app folder and now everything is fine.