# How to fetch the list of near by wifi networks and able to connect to them from our App in ios (Using private API for enterprise App)?

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, wifi, iphone-privateapi

I want to fetch the list of near by wifi networks and able to connect to them from our App in ios, and my Application is Enterprise App so even private api's is also fine. Stuck this issue since 2 weeks, please provide me some references..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require will only work on JailBroken devices, the blog(blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170) which @Ckouta referred also has one comment from the Blog Admin,

I’m assuming that your device is already jailbroken (otherwise not possible)
You shall create release build of sample app and upload release build in to /Applications folder.
(you can use open ssh for that )

Answer (score 1):

Public API allows you to have only information about the current wifi used by your device using [`CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo)

In order to fetch all the wifi available in your area, take a look at: [`Stumbler`](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler) which is using [`MobileApple80211`](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions). I think, it handles what you are looking for. Moreover, you can also use it to connect your device to a specific wifi. You can find a good example of what you need [here](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/issues/detail?id=20) (answer #9)

Just keep in mind, if you are using private API, your app will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: Will it for non-jail broken devices?

Comment: I never test personally on non-jail broken devices, but following the two first comments from this article (http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/), I suppose, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's late but have a look at [this link](https://github.com/Cykey/wifi). You can do what you want with the use of `MobileWifi.framework` and thanks to Cykey there are some reversed headers to use. I have done what you want myself using the link above:)